# Java accessing static inner class potentially throw NoSuchFieldException

Tags: java, inner-classes

In Java why calling a static nested class won't compile because of a potential NoSuchFieldException and IllegalArgumentEception ?

Here is my classes:

```
public class DBRef {
    public static class CMS_FILE_ROOM extends BuildableDatabaseTable {

        public static String _table_name = "cms_file_ROOM";
        public static BuildableColumn _ALL = new BuildableColumn._ALL(getCurrentClass());

    }


    public static SelectQuery SELECT(final BuildableColumn... columnsToSelect) {
        return new SelectQuery(columnsToSelect);
    }
}

public class SelectQuery extends Query {

    public SelectQuery(final BuildableColumn... columnsToSelect) {
        super();
        for (final BuildableColumn column : columnsToSelect) {
            this.columns.add(column.toSQL());
        }
    }

    public Query FROM(final Class<? extends BuildableDatabaseTable> tableClass) throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
        this.froms.add(DatabaseAccesser.toSQL(tableClass));
        return this;
    }
}

// Method called in both cases just above by some poor designed methods redirection (my bad). But exceptions are catched.
public static String toSQL(final Class<? extends BuildableDatabaseTable> table) {
    try {
        return (String) table.getField("_table_name").get(null);
    } catch (final IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (final NoSuchFieldException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "ERROR";
}
```

When from anywhere else in my code I do:

```
SelectQuery lSelectQuery = (SelectQuery) DBRef.SELECT(DBRef.CMS_FILE_ROOM._ALL)
            .FROM(DBRef.CMS_FILE_ROOM.class);
```

I get the following (compile time) error (on the .class call):
[image: Error message]

I can't find the reason why, I can nest this in a try catch but I'd like to understand why ?

Comment: usually `nosuchfieldexception` is related to reflection, are you doing any? post more relevant code where the problem occurs.

Comment: No reflection at all. I updated my code.

Comment: mostly `DBRef.SELECT` is doing some reflection, as it loads selected data into an instance of the passed class, can you post the whole exception, it may mention which field is the problem, could be something like `un-sync` between the db-table and the class members, also could be something related to static inner classes and static members.

Comment: @OP Could you please give us a complete example (preferrably a single .java file that shows the error)? Is it a compile or a runtime error? Is the spelling of the exceptions really lowercase or was it NoSuchFieldException, IllegalArgumentException? Where do the classes SelectQuery, BuildableDatabaseTable, BuildableColumn and their relevant methods come from? Too many things we have to guess, so don't expect a useful answer - or add the information we need.

Comment: Provide a [mcve].

Comment: Ok, reading back my post, it missed infos obviously. Now it should be a lot better. @Ralf. It's a compile time error in CamelCase. For the classes, I let you check my edit. Thx